# How to configure Underscore syntax in visual studio? label js

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, syntax, label

With **Sublime Text 3** I can configure the syntax for **HTML (Underscore)** in a simple way.

Does anyone know how I do the same with **VS Code**?

[Sublime Text 3  /  VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mnsR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I was typing "label" when I was supposed to type "babel".